# Is there any way to get array value using ngForm in angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-forms

For example, I wrote a component like this.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    template:
        `
        <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
            <input type="text" ngControl="people">
            <input type="text" ngControl="people">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    `
})
export class Home {
    onSubmit(f) {
        console.log(f.value);
    }
}
```

When I input "tom" and "bob" for each form and click "Submit" button, console says:

```
Object {people: "bob"}
```

Whereas my expectation is:

```
Object {people: ["tom", "bob"]}
```

Is it possible to get array value using ngForm?

Comment: Why are you even using 2 input controls? You have several options here - 1) Use 1 input box and accept comma separated values, then make it an array using split function.This will work irrespective of how many people you are accepting. 2) If you are accepting exactly 2 people only than create 2 different names like person1 and person2 , then make an array like this - `people = [person1,person2];`. What do you think?

Comment: The number of people varies in my product. Your first solution may work well in my case. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: That's great! I'll add it as a answers so that others could benefit. Ok?

Comment: I found a good way which meets my requirements. See [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37004087/2267825).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example which meets my requirement using [ControlArray](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/ControlArray-class.html).

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, Control, FORM_PROVIDERS, FormBuilder} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
        selector: 'home',
        template:
            `
            <form [ngFormModel]="sampleForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(sampleForm)">
                <div ngControlGroup="people">
                    <div *ngFor="let item of sampleForm.controls.people.controls; let i = index">
                        <input type="text" ngControl='{{ i }}'>
                        <button (click)="delPerson(i)">Del</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button (click)="addPerson($event)">Add</button>
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
        `,
        providers: [FORM_PROVIDERS]
    })
export class Home {

    sampleForm: any;

    constructor(private builder: FormBuilder) {
        this.sampleForm = this.builder.group({
            people: this.builder.array([new Control()])
        });
    }

    addPerson(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.sampleForm.controls.people.push(new Control());
    }

    delPerson(i: number) {
        this.sampleForm.controls.people.removeAt(i);
    }

    onSubmit(f) {
        console.log(f.value);
    }
}
```

This works well for me, but I think this part (`let item of sampleForm.controls.people.controls`) is not beautiful and I don't know this is a good usage of ngForm.

Comment: Actually, it's using old api. You should try to use the reactive form in latest Angular4.

Answer (score 0):

I would create `ngModel` / control compliant sub component for your people:

```
const PEOPLE_VALUE_ACCESSOR = new Provider(
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {useExisting: forwardRef(() => PeopleComponent), multi: true});

@Component({
  selector: 'people',
  template: `
    <div>
      Person 1 : <input [(ngModel)]="person1" (ngModelChange)="doOnChange()"/><br/>
      Person 2 : <input [(ngModel)]="person2" (ngModelChange)="doOnChange()"/>
    <div>
  `,
  providers: [ PEOPLE_VALUE_ACCESSOR ]
})
export class PeopleComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  onChange = (_) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};

  writeValue(value:any):void {
    if (value!=null) {
      this.person1 = value[0];
      this.person2 = value[1];
    }
  }

  doOnChange(elt) {
    this.onChange([ this.person1, this.person2 ]);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void { this.onChange = fn; }
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void { this.onTouched = fn; }
}
```

You can use it this way:

```
<form>
  <div>
    <people #people="ngForm" ngControl="people"></people>
    people : {{people.value}}
  </div>
</form>
```

Within the associated control (`people.value` here), you will have an array.

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/ix8unZ58hvqojjAic0E3?p=preview.